# Office add-in error registration error - Component not correctly registered

Tags: excel, ms-word, ms-office, add-in

We have a Office add-in component that is built in VB 6. We register it by running command as OfficeConnector.exe /regserver with admin rights that works most of the time for any MS office versions. In one of the machine with Office 2013 installation, Add-in registration fails with error as "Component not correctly registered". We tried repairing the office installation, still the same error happens. Any suggestion on this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work on other machines with the 2013 version? Should you upgrade?> Or did you upgrade and now it does not work?

Comment: It works for 2013 also in most of the machines.

Comment: Have you tried contacting add-in developers instead?